Getting error connecting a Web API to PostgreSQL
I am switching from SQL Server to PostgreSQL, and have a Web API that I have updated as follows.
In the appsettings.json file, I have:
{
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "MPmain": "Data Source=DESKTOP-FCT8VC2;Initial Catalog=mpau;Integrated Security=True;TrustServerCertificate=true",
        "MPpostgres1": "User ID=postgres;Password=xxxxxxxx;Server=localhost;Port=5432;Database=mpau;",
        "MPpostgres": "host=localhost port=5432 dbname=mpau user=postgres password=xxxxxxxx connect_timeout=10 sslmode=prefer"
    },
    "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Information",
            "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
        }
    },
    "AllowedHosts": "*"
}

And in the Program.cs file, I have:
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Npgsql;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

//added
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddDefaultPolicy(
        policy =>
        {
            policy.AllowAnyOrigin();
            policy.AllowAnyMethod();
            policy.AllowAnyHeader();
        });
});

//added
builder.Services.AddDbContext<mpauDbContext>(options =>
{
    builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("MPpostgres1");
    options.UseNpgsql("MPpostgres1");

});


builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();

I was able to create the data migrations, however when I try update-database, I get an error stating:

Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification at index 0"

In the appsettings.json file, MPmain was the string used for SQL Server (which worked fine), and I also tried putting the computer name instead of localhost in both MPpostgres1 and MPpostgres strings, also with no change. MPpostgres was the connection string taken directly from pgAdmin4, copy/pasted.
Most search results state that it is likely caused by an error in the connection string, but I have tried multiple changes, and I followed a tutorial where the string used was almost identical (with the exception of username and password, and I will be trying Kerberos authentication later to remove this from the connection string).
UPDATE: I tested all of the above on the .NET 7 webAPI version, including the connection string MPpostgres1, and was able to complete the migration and generate the tables. The error appears to be specific to the .NET 8 version of the webAPI.
Any help in resolving this error would be greatly appreciated.

Just to clarify, commenting out the "builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("postgres");" line did not produce a change, and adding the "AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql()" after the "Services." in the AddDbContext led to a warning that it may cause conflict of some kind, so I removed it, although the tutorial in the video seemed to work fine. However adding it also did not resolve the issue of the error.

Did you change the connection string when going from SQL Server to Postgresql?  You now have a two port application.  Port 1 is a HTTP client server connection (frontend) Port 2 is a server to database connection (backend).  You should be using the same connection string in Postgresql as with SQL Server.  You have to make sure the Server is the same.  So localhost may need to get changed to an IP.   The credentials should also be the same.  So you have to make sure the server passes the client credentials to the backend database.  I need to know what you changed in the connection string.

Thank you @jdweng for your time. I have added the connection strings that I tried to the post. MPmain was the string used for SQL server, and I tried this after your comment but it produced no change. I also tried putting the computer name instead of localhost in both MPpostgres1 and MPpostgres strings, also with no change. Is it possible that this type of error could be caused by a completely different reason, or is it necessarily a connection string issue? Many thanks again for your time and support.

You must use the same connection string as SQL Server.  You are not creating a new database but connecting to the same old database.  Integrated Security=True is using the user credentials.  So Postgresql server frontend must pass the client credentials to the backend database.  I think you want use SSPI authentication.  See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/auth-methods.html

If you still have issue, use SQL Server Management Studio to connect to database.  Check log file in explorer under management.  When you run your application there will be a entry in the log file contains success/failure and the Group/User that attempted to connect to the database.  Make sure the Group/User is the same that worked with SQL Server connection.  If it is not the same the postgresql authentication mode is wrong.

Please forgive my ignorance for this next question if it is silly: I am actually creating a new database, with PostgreSQL as the engine. I was able to create the migrations successfully in VS 2022, but got the error when using update-database to add the new tables to the new PostgreSQL database. Does this change the situation, meaning the connection string should be different than that used for SQL Server which is a different DB technology/engine? Again, apologies if that seems like a silly question to you, @jdweng

The connection string with migration and postgreSQL should be the same.  You need to get migration to pass.  Forget what I said about SQL Server since you are creating a new database.  Did you run Migration on same machine that is you server for postresql?  Once you get migration to work the next step is to get the connection string to work with the client.  You may have credential issue if client and server are on different machines.  The credentials you are using in postresql may need to be changed to work with a client on a different machine.

Yes, I am using the same single computer to run the migration as the server for Postgres. I am not using different machines, just in the development phase right now. I have set up a new project, based on .NET 8, and basically starting from scratch (just brought in the controllers and models from previous project). The migration worked and I have it showing successfully generated in my project in VS 2022. It is just the connection string, based on everything you have shared, with many thanks as always for your time.

The Controller has to be consistent with the credentials you are using in postresql.  For example, if you have in the controller [Authorize] the client credentials get passed to the backend.  The postresql must allow the credentials for the client.  What connection string is migration using?

It is using the MPpostgres1 string. When I did "add-migration" in the package manager console, it produced the new migrations folder. I then tried "update-database" without changing the connection string, and it produced the error. I have since tried modifying the string in many, many ways, with no luck getting "update-database" to work. I have not started to use [Authorize] in the controllers yet, although using JWT will be my next step once I get the connection string to work. I wanted to take everything one step at a time, and have gotten stuck with this relatively simple step.

Try to create a new database with migration to see if there is errors in your model (or possible a credential error).  Make sure you know what connection string migration is using so you can use the same with postresql.  You also must know if the credentials with postresql is coming from the client.  The prefer method is to pass the frontend (client) credentials to the backend.  When you are using migration that is probably not happening.  Step one is to get migration working.  Step two is to get credentials working with client connection.

See Migrate Migrations : https://developers.redhat.com/articles/2024/01/11/connect-dotnet-app-external-postgresql-database#ensuring_secure_communication

Thank you very much @jdweng for the support. I'll continue trying to get it working. Your time is sincerely appreciated.

Please see the update added to the original question regarding .NET 7 vs .NET 8 for further clarification.

I was able to resolve the issue by changing the parsing of the configuration settings in the Program.cs file. The solution was to use:
options.UseNpgsql(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("MPpostgres1"));

instead of:
builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("MPpostgres1");
options.UseNpgsql("MPpostgres1");

I believe this is due to the way configuration is handled differently between .NET versions. Hopefully this resolution helps anyone experiencing a similar error.
